# Python : child function unable to access parent function data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to pass data to child function from parent function but I am failing , please help

```
>>> def funa():
    a=10
    b=20
    funb()


>>> def funb():
    c=a+b
    print(c)


>>> funa()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#32>", line 1, in <module>
    funa()
  File "<pyshell#27>", line 4, in funa
    funb()
  File "<pyshell#31>", line 2, in funb
    c=a+b
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: in the function **funcb** define a and b variables

Comment: 'a' and 'b' are local variable of function `funa` . they can not access in other function.

Comment: `a` and `b` are not global

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
def funa():
    a=10
    b=20
    funb(a,b)

def funb(a,b):
    c=a+b
    print(c)
```

Comment: Good idea , Thank you Pavan

Answer (score 3):

When you define a variable in a function then it is local to the function.  This is known as *local scope*.  There are a couple of ways around this.  What you are looking for is *global scope*, and you can do it in Python like this:

```
def funa():
    global a
    global b
    a=10
    b=20
    funb()
```

Phew!  That's messy!  Yes, and for good reason.  This is a BAD design.  Generally speaking it is poor practice to use global variables in this way because the two functions are now tied together, not just with themselves but with the rest of the program.  GOOD design is that they are *encapsulated*, that is they are independent:

```
def funa():
    a=10
    b=20
    funb(a, b)

def funb(a, b):
    c=a+b
    print(c)
```

Why?  Because now `funa()` and `funb()` can be used elsewhere.  We don't even have to call these values `a` and `b` anymore.  I can now use the goodness that is in `funb()` from other functions.  If I put `funb()` into a module I can even use it in other programs as well.  This means we don't have to write the same code twice (the principle is called DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself).  If you make code that is stand-alone and independent then there is a greater chance you can reuse it.

Answer (score 2):

Use **pass by value** method as Pavan given in his answer.

OR Use **[global](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php)** variable method:

```
>>> a = 10
>>> b = 20
>>> 
>>> def test():
...   global a, b
...   a = 1
...   b = 2
...   test1()
... 
>>> def test1():
...    print "a:", a, "\tb:", b
... 
>>> test()
a: 1    b: 2
>>>
```